# Visual Studio 2015 Not Working

Tags: devenv, visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition multiple times, and trying to repair it multiple times, I have nearly given up. Every time it finishes, I either get into the application or not at all, and I am encountered with the infamous 'Visual Studio has stopped working'. From doing /Log, I have found the following errors:

```
<entry>
    <record>2254</record>
    <time>2016/01/01 03:05:17.135</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\FW5M2DRW.N5T\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TEAMFOUNDATION\TEAM EXPLORER\</path>
</entry>
```

and,

```
<entry>
    <record>2009</record>
    <time>2016/01/01 03:05:14.867</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2EF1EC52-C8BF-4FE0-8ECE-BA9C0D5D1603}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: 'VSMenus.ctmenu'.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

I am desperate for an answer, as I really need to get it working. I have reinstalled, repaired, and waited, but nothing works. Any help will be considered.

Some notes:

- Recently upgraded to Windows 10 Pro, before upgrade it worked
- I have tried Enterprise and Professional, none have worked either
- I have tried resetting settings, user data, safemode, etc. None have worked

Comment: did you try uninstalling the TFS components?

Answer (score -1):

don't panic about this. Try to uninstall TFS (Team Foundation Server) components.
Or
Give it a try. Uninstall SQL Server if it is already installed. After removing SQL, install VS 2015.
After VS 2015, you can install SQL.